# How would I add an APNG or GIF at Konva stage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, konvajs

I want to add a GIF and APNG object, just like I add a static image at Konva stage. The problem is when I add an APNG or GIF, it only shows the first frame. I am using React Konva. Is there any way to add APNG and GIF images at Konva stage?

Comment: The GIF/APNG is working at Safari but not in the Chrome!